# `strip` Python method non-obvious behavior

Tags: python, strip

I was surprised about `strip` Python method behavior:

```
>>> 'https://texample.com'.strip('https://')
'example.com'
```

It was not obvious, because usually I use `strip` with an one-char argument.

This is because of

> The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed

(https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

What is the best way to delete a "head" of a string?

Comment: Strip strips all of the characters passed, regardless of sequence, which explains the output. The answer below suggesting `replace` is correct.

Comment: You might not think the existing behavior is obvious, but the typical usage would be to do things like remove all whitespace from the ends of a string, and for that, you'd want to be able to remove all characters from a specified set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 3 options:

1. use `string.replace` instead of `string.strip`
2. `startswith` method:

```
    if line.startswith("'https://"):
        return line[8:]
```

3. split:

```
    if "/" in line:
        param, value = line.split("/",1)
```